# What does property access in a for-of loop do, like `for (a.b of c)`?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I encountered this obscure syntax:

```js
const a = {}
const c = [1,2,3]

for (a.b of c) {}

assert(a.b === 3)
```

How does it work?

Comment: You just re-use a variable. Same as if you had done `let current; for (current of someArray)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just puts each iteration value into that property value of the existing object.

```js
const a = {}
const c = [1,2,3]

for (a.b of c) {
  console.log(a.b);
}
console.log(a.b);
console.log(a);
```

It can be any existing reference:

```js
const a = {
  foo: [
    {
      nested: 'nestedVal'
    }
  ]
}
const c = [1,2,3]

for (a.foo[0].nested of c) {
  console.log(a.foo[0].nested);
}
console.log(a.foo[0].nested);
console.log(a);
```

Including a standalone variable:

```js
let a;
const c = [1,2,3]

for (a of c) {
  console.log(a);
}
console.log('a is:', a);
```

Or you can create a binding for each iteration with `const` or `let`, eg `const item of c`, as you probably already know.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? First time seeing this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily have a look at by logging the `a` variable.

By assigning `a.b` you hold the value of iteration at `b` property of `a`.

Please have a look at the following snippet:

```js
const a = {}
console.log(a);

const c = [1,2,3]

for (a.b of c) {
  console.log(a);
}
```

Hope this helps.